# read data from database got error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this code read the data from database where i have 3 tables i want trying to print the title which is course and its details in module table but i got an error saying Unknown column 'SCQF07' in 'where clause'  can give me advice how to solve this problem thanks in advance

```
<?php
    $m = new mysqli("localhost","user","pwd","courses");
    if ($m->connect_errno)
    {
        die("Database connection failed");
    }
    $m->set_charset('utf8');
    $i = $_REQUEST['ide'];

    $sql = "SELECT module.level, module.credits, cm.course, module.school, course.title
              from cm
              join module on (module = module.id)
              join course on (course = course.id)
              where  module = $i";

    $res = $m->query($sql) or die($m->error);
    $CastArray = Array();
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();

?>

<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><?php  echo "$row[tile] - <a href=movies3.php?ide=$row[course]>$row[title]</a>"; ?></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

table  course

```
 id primary key      
 title     
 href     
level   
 award   
summary  
 dept     
 subject  
overview 
 wyl      
careers
```

table  cm

```
course foreign key
module  foreign key
num
```

table module

```
id      primary key
title       
level 
credits       
school
```

Comment: where are you setting "$i" and what it the query you have before the H1 to allow the setting of the variables in the heading? - also  is it a typo in the heading line "$row[tile]" should be "$row[title]"?

Comment: thanks - and the typo? in the heading? or is it supposed the be "tile"? the the $i is wrapped in <?php ?> I presume? and there is a form somewhere that yields the request of "ide"?

Comment: The code shown is incomplete - how is $sql executed?  How is $row generated?

Comment: your join conditions are incomplete

Comment: Why are you vandalizing your own post?

Comment: With respect, Stack Overflow questions and the contributed and upvoted answers aren't just for you; they help a whole community. It's best if you refrain from deleting them: someone else may have a similar problem and learn from your experience.

Answer (score 2):

Your value `$_REQUEST['ide']` contains non-numeric characters. Thus, the where clause

```
WHERE module = $i
```

expands to something like

```
WHERE module = SCQF07
```

and MySQL interprets the unquoted string `SCQF07` as a column name. You need to either

1. change your query to

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT module.level, module.credits, cm.course, module.school, course.title
         from cm
         join module on (module = module.id)
         join course on (course = course.id)
         where  module = '$i'"
   ```

(note the single quotes around `$i`), or

2. switch to using prepared statements, which automagically handle quoting, escaping and type-matching and also provide a measure of protection against [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?s=1%7C32.9683).

To retrieve all rows of the result you need to call `fetch` repeatedly. This is usually done within a `while` loop, like so:

```
<?php
    $res = $m->query($sql) or die($m->error);
    $CastArray = Array();

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
    {
?>
    <h1><?php  echo "{$row['title']} - <a href=movies3.php?ide={$row['course']}>{$row['title']}</a>"; ?></h1>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yes. That's what I want. Does the query look as you expected it to look?

Comment: Then are you sure this is the block of code that's causing trouble? I just ran the query on my own system and it worked fine.

Comment: See my revised solution.

Comment: Can you add the `echo $sql;` statement to the page at napier.ac.uk so I can see what's going on there?

Comment: Now it's working for me. Do you need to clear your browser's cache?

Comment: soory what should can i just message you back  after having my dinner

Comment: Sure. No big rush.

Comment: `fetch_*` only retrieves one row from the resultset. You need to make repeated calls to get all the rows. Do you need me to illustrate?

Comment: @GreenlinelLine That's not up to me. The mods are apparently discussing it now.